# How to customize hibernate @ElementCollection envers audit table name?

Tags: java, hibernate-envers

I'm currently using **Hibernate & Envers version 5.2.9.Final**. I want to use **@ElementCollection** with a **custom table name** for both the **collection and the audit table**.

What I know so far is that modifying default table names has a variety of annotations to work with: For the entity itself there are the annotations @Table and @SecondaryTable as well as the corresponding envers annotations @AuditTable and @SecondaryAuditTable. For changing the table name of an element collection there is the @CollectionTable annotaion. I have not been able to find a corresponding envers annotation so far. So my question is:

***How can I change the name for a hibernate @ElementCollection envers audit table?***

---

**Additional info**

In the [hibernate envers ticket which tracks the adding of auditing support](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6613) for element collections, the same question was asked back in 2013 but not answered.

A **code snippet** to make my setup clear:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
@SecondaryTable(name = "\"user_secondary\"")
@Audited
@AuditTable("\"user_audit\"")
@SecondaryAuditTable(secondaryTableName = "user_secondary",
        secondaryAuditTableName = "\"user_secondary_audit\"")
public class User {

    // ... stuff like id and other fields ...

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "\"user_references\"")
    private Map<String, Long> references = new HashMap<>();
    // TODO FIXME how to get a custom name for the audit table?

    // ... more stuff like getters and setters
}
```

Hibernate generates all tables as intended, yet the **collecction audit table is named 'user_references_AUD'** while *I would like* to get the name **'user_references_audit'** like for the other tables.

I'm also *aware of the global settings affecting the audit table prefix or suffix*, but that is only a last resort for my use case.

---

**Update**

As suggested I added a [feature request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11595) to Hibernate JIRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Envers has no complement for `@CollectionTable`.

You are welcomed to add a [JIRA](https://hibernate.atlassian.net) requesting that we add a complementing annotation and I can look at what is needed to add the functionality.  Just at a glance, it shouldn't require too much as it merely needs to feed into the generated Envers entity table name for the collection middle entity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and the offer! I was about to do that anyways, but first I needed to register. So here is the feature request: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11595

Comment: Hi @Naros , Still there is no support for @CollectionTable?